# WordPress Visual Composer Unable to fetch and show the content when image is inserted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom vc_map in my function and here is my Code:

```
vc_map( array(
  'name' => __( 'myname Article Content', 'myname' ),
  'base' => 'myname-article-content', //my shortcode name
  'class' => '',
  'icon' => 'icon-wpb-vc_carousel',
  'category' => __( 'Content', 'myname' ),
  'description' => __( 'Content for Article', 'myname' ),
  'params' => array(
    array(
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'heading' => __( 'Image Caption', 'myname' ),
      'param_name' => 'caption',
      'description' => __( 'Enter text which will be used as Image    Caption.', 'myname' )
      ),
    array(
      'type' => 'textfield',
      'heading' => __( 'Image credits', 'myname' ),
      'param_name' => 'credits',
      'description' => __( 'Enter text which will be used as Image credits. Leave blank if no title is needed.', 'myname' )
      ),
    array(
      'type'        => 'textarea_html',
      'holder'      => 'div',
      'heading'     => __( 'Content', 'myname' ),
      'param_name'  => 'body_text',
      'description' => __( 'Enter the Body of the news', 'myname' )
      )
    )
  ) );
```

and here is my short code:

```
add_shortcode('myname-article-content','myname_article_content');

function myname_article_content($atts){

  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'caption' =>'',
    'credits' => '',
    'body_text'=> ''
    ), $atts ); 

  extract($atts);

  $cat = get_the_category()
?>
<span class="category"><?php echo $cat[0]->name;?></span>
        <h2 class="popular-business"><?php the_title();?></h2>
        <div class="post-author"><strong>Published by:</strong> <?php the_author(); ?> <strong>Published Date</strong> <?php the_date(); ?></div>
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
        $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); 
        else:  
          $feat_image_url = MYTHEME_THEME_DIR_URI.'/assets/images/blank-img.png';
        endif;?>
        <div class="post-img" >
          <img src="<?php echo $feat_image_url ?>" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <p><?php echo $caption;?></p>
        <?php if($credits != '') {?>
        <p><strong>PHOTO BY</strong> <?php echo $credits;?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        <hr class="divider-full">
        <p><?php echo $body_text;?></p>
        <?php add_action('myname_text', $body_text); ?>
        <div class="gap gap-30"></div>
<p><strong>Share</strong></p>
<div class="gap gap-30"></div>

<?php
}
```

in this codes.. the only thing that is not working properly is the textarea_html in my visual composer.

if the content has no image added the vc_map is operational in the editor and in the frontend.

But when I add an image, after saving the content in the editor, the contents in the textarea_html will be shown in the holder and that's where it should be, BUT when i click edit again it can't fetch the content of the textarea_html but the other contents like textfields are shown.

and another thing, when i click update post.. if there is no image added the post is working fine in the frontend, but when i add image or any media the content cannot be shown.

any ideas? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I found help on this [Envato support page].(https://forums.envato.com/t/render-visual-composer-shortcodes-onto-page/126965)

For others searching, this is how you echo `textarea_html` content from Visual Composer. Read this if `textarea_html` is not echoing or your `textarea_htm`l is not working.

If you check method 2, you will see that `$content` is passed as an argument along with `$atts`.

In your case, you need to change the `param_name` to `content`:

```
array(
    'type'        => 'textarea_html',
    'holder'      => 'div',
    'heading'     => __( 'Content', 'myname' ),
    'param_name'  => 'content',
    'description' => __( 'Enter the Body of the news', 'myname' )
)
```

...and pass in the `$content` variable:

`function myname_article_content($atts, $content)`

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Thanks for this... The visual composer documentation says nothing about passing the $content as separate value instead of as part of $atts.

Comment: No problem! When I worked out what the hell I was doing wrong I knew other people would also be hitting a brick wall. Visual composer is great but the docs could be more developer friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works for me,

1. your `param_name` should be content.
2. you will require to pass `$content` along with `$atts` in the function that you use for returning HTML.
3. make sure you don't define content within `shortcode_atts`.

Here's an example:

```
    public function render_html( $atts , $content) {
         
        // Params extraction
        extract(
            shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'image'   => '',
                    'title'   => '',
                    'button_text'   => '',
                    'button_url'   => '',
                ), 
                $atts
            )
        );
        $html = '';
        $html = include('templates/render-html.php'); // this will include my page html
        return $html;
    }
```